# Refactoring Folder Structure for React and TypeScript Project with Three.js Business Logic

Tags: reactjs, typescript, three.js, directory-structure, project-structure

I'm working on a React and TypeScript project that consists of three layers: business logic (implemented using Three.js), view (React components), and store (communication between business logic and view). I'm planning to refactor the project's folder structure, as the current structure is causing cross-imports between folders.

The current structure is as follows:

```
src/app contains the business logic, including subfolders like utils, types, and constants.
src/components, src/modules, and src/pages contain the React components.
```

I'm considering separating the React-related files into a separate folder under src, named something like view or react.

Can someone suggest a better folder structure for this project?

Here's a screenshot of the current project structure with all the business logic in src/app and React components in src/components, src/modules, and src/pages.
[image: Current project structure]